# modelderivative/v2/designdata/<urn>/metadata/<guid> call not returning data

Tags: autodesk-forge

My app uploads a .rvt file to a bucket and converts it to an SVF for use in the viewer. This process has worked until today when the process starts to hang while waiting for data to comeback from the modelderivative/v2/designdata//metadata/ call. Nothing has changed on our end code wise and I've tried models that succeeded yesterday. Does anyone know if there are issues with the Forge Service today?

Comment: Show your code and the error as well

Comment: Has this model worked in the past? What is the size of the model? Are you using the viewer to check if it is translating correctly?

Comment: Hi @Ben, are you using JAVA and the JAVA SDK? probably you hit the known issue we have addressed recently.  The other post tells more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573466/model-derivative-api-responses-not-mapping-through-jackson. I guess you hit the similar issue of #2 in the other post.

Comment: We're using node.js. It started working again for the revit file a few hours after posting, but yes the model had worked in the past. It is 5.3MB. The file showed in the viewer just fine, but we were unable to pull metadata.

Comment: Hi Ben, When you do the call, what status code are you getting is it the 202? have you try the end point a couple of times more until you get the 200 status, this will give you back the Metadata.