# Function getManifest Autodesk forge PHP client

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was wondering if you can help me with a problem I have related to the forge php client found at:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-php-client

I am trying to get manifest status after translation job is done using:

```
$derivatives_api = new Autodesk\Forge\Client\Api\DerivativesApi($auth);
$manifest_status = $derivatives_api->getManifest($urn, null)->getStatus();
```

`$auth` variable contains scope data read, data write etc.
$urn should be correct, I checked it also

At first two attempts I got value "inprogress" but after that:
Invalid value for 'role', must be one of '2d', '3d', 'graphics', 'manifest', 'thumbnail'

I then went to the ManifestChildren.php and printed $role in setRole function and got that role is none of the above ('2d', '3d', 'graphics', 'manifest', 'thumbnail') but it happens to be 'Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase'

Is there anything I can to to get the proper status by using getManifest function?

I am trying to get metadata as well but first I wanna check the status using manifest...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the question/answer at [Issue with getManifest (forge-php-client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945805/issue-with-getmanifest-forge-php-client?rq=1), I believe it's the same issue, and copied the answer here:

The error seems to be a bug that occurs because new roles for ManifestChildren.role were defined without beeing declared within the model.

PROPERTYDB -> Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase (e.g. this is one missing 'role')

As workaround (that worked for me) just set the parameter "accept_encoding" of getManifest() to 'gzip':

$result = $apiInstance->getManifest( $correctObject, 'gzip' );
Everything works fine now.

I will log this issue to PHP client.